# How to decode and verify password in feathers js

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, feathersjs

I am new to feathersJs and trying to learn how to perform authentication using hooks and services. I am using Couchdb database and cradle.
This is the post method to encrypt password in hashPassword using "users" hooks service. The post method is as below:

```
app.post('/dev',function(req,res,next){
   var  username = req.body.username;
   var password = req.body.password;
   app.service('database').create({username,password}).then(user => {
     db.save(user, function (err, docs) {
      // Handle response
      res.json(docs);
         });
      console.log('User Created Successfully.', user);
    }).catch(console.error);
  })
```

and service is:

```
app.service('authentication').hooks({
  before: {
    create: [
      // You can chain multiple strategies
      auth.hooks.authenticate(['jwt', 'local'])
    ],
    remove: [
      auth.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
    ]
  }
});

app.service('database').hooks({
  before: {
    find: [
      auth.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
    ],
    create: [
      local.hooks.hashPassword({ passwordField: 'password' })
    ]
  }
});
```

now i am using this to retrive data :

```
app.post('/devget',function(req,res,next){

        var User = {
              username: req.body.username,
              password: req.body.password
            };
            app.service('dataget').find(User).then(user => {
            db.view('byuser/user',{key: User.username}, function (err, docs) {
                  // Handle response
                  res.json(docs);
              });
              console.log('User Get Successfully.', user);
            }).catch(console.error);
    })
```

this will give me data in response as:

```
Response [
  { id: '060ab48a4826da7125d8ae45350037ee',
    key: 'w',
    value: 
     { _id: '060ab48a4826da7125d8ae45350037ee',
       _rev: '1-ea9a18d3724ce4542019dc5752c1fd4d',
       username: 'w',
       password: '$2a$10$yBJVJTmVXfTk0V4CCiWkd.GvAZZB9dF2pckKJ9wb/lJcAK8Ou.v06',
       id: 0 } } ]
```

this works fine and password is encrypted but i am not getting how to decrypt password and authenticate user.

**Note: i just want  o do it with hooks and services or custom service or class but not using passport.**

Comment: You can user [feathers-authentication](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication) to authenticate the user. If you want to create your own then better to user your own password hashing. But if you will use feathers then check how they hash your password [here](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication-local/blob/master/src/utils/hash.js).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not decrypt the password; you compare the encrypted password to a function that will encrypt the password (after you've found the user to make a password comparison to).

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


var hash = bcrypt.hashSync("bacon");

bcrypt.compareSync("bacon", hash); // true
bcrypt.compareSync("veggies", hash); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `comparePassword` function in this file

https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/blob/be5d8df3b7afa39852ff1b5643676d9140ba8203/packages/authentication-local/src/strategy.ts#L94

Based on that you could write a hook and consider contributing it to the feathersJS project.